# Silverstripe cache flush does not persist

Tags: silverstripe

First time working with SilverStripe (Version 3.6), I'm really struggling with the caching when working on a site in a local development environment (Mac OSX, PHP7.1, Apache2.4).

When viewing a page on the website, I can add `?flush` or `?flush=all` to the URL and flush the cache. By doing this I can see changes I make to templates or CSS. It's a faff, but manageable.

However if I remove the flush query param, the page reverts back to some previous version.

I would expect the flush action to clear all caches and allow me to see the most up to date version of the page, without having to always have the `?flush` param.

I have a `/silverstripe-cache` directory which is writable, and I can see files generated in it.

What am I doing wrong? Why is Silverstripe caching some older version of the pages, despite my use of flush?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the answer to this is in the `/cache` directory (which I've just discovered).

```
rm -rf cache/*
```

Removes all files in the cache directory, and appears to resolve my issues of cached HTML and CSS, and means I don't need to add `?flush` to every request.

The cache folder is remaining empty on subsequent page loads, possibly because the SilverStripe site is running in `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE=dev` mode. I assume when it's live (`SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE=live`) then the cache folder will be used.